# CSS rounded box

Tags: css

This is probably a very beginner question but that's what I am in CSS. I have this:

```
<div id="box">
        SAMPLE TEXT TO DISPLAY IN BOX!
</div>
```

And the css to this box is in an external sheet (which is correctly linked to the html page):

```
#box {
border-radius: 28px; 
-moz-border-radius: 28px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 28px; 
border: 5px solid #3B5998;
}
```

When I try to use the code in my page it just doesn't work! Any idea why? Again sorry if the question is too simple :)

EDIT: The box i used within another div that is center. Here is how its' used:

```
<div id="center">
    <div id="box">
        Hdadjlsd
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is the css for center:

```
#center { 
margin-right:200px;
background-color:white; 
min-height:700px; /* for modern browsers */
height:auto !important; /* for modern browsers */
height:700px; /* for IE5.x and IE6 */
}
```

outside of this tag it works.

EDIT: Screenshot showing the problem as highlighted by chrome. It is showing where the red boxs is now when inspecting element[image]

Comment: It is working perfectly fine. What browser are you using? Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/r8HZp/

Comment: works for me. IE8 doesn't support border-radius: http://jsfiddle.net/7nn8k/

Comment: Care to show screenshot? Btw, 28px is too big for rounded corners, typically it's about 10-12px max.

Comment: it's fine give to padding for text http://jsfiddle.net/r8HZp/1/

Comment: Chrome support border-radius http://blog.shamess.info/2009/04/21/chromes-border-radius-css-feature/

Comment: strange then and thanks for using jsfiddle to show the expected outcome...still now working for me though

Comment: I tried pasting same code in new CSS and new HTML and it shows in chrome. But in my current page, it doesn't. What could that mean?

Comment: may the box influenced by center div

Answer (score 2):

copy paste this code into your html check whether its working or not . im sure it does if your using chrome :)  , if it works then type the css into your html and run it.

```
 <html>
  <head>
  <style type="text/css"> 
   div
 {
 border:2px solid #a1a1a1;
 padding:10px 40px; 
 background:#dddddd;
 width:300px;
 border-radius:25px;
 }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div>The border-radius property allows you to add rounded corners to elements.</div> 
 </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Then the your page has problem.

Comment: I am editing the question to include the div in which it is placed.

Comment: load the website, and click on F12 button on your keyboard, a new window will popup from the bottom of the chrome window, you will mostly see a "X" mark on bottom right, click on it , it will display what resource it failed to load.

Answer (score 0):

have you **tried including the css inside the page**?? general trend is to use such CSS inside the page not as external links.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like these codes;

```
-moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px #000000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px #000000;
 box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px #000000;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 28px;
-moz-border-radius-topright:28px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft:28px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright:28px;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius:28px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius:28px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:28px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:28px;
border-top-left-radius:28px;
border-top-right-radius:28px;
border-bottom-left-radius:28px;
border-bottom-right-radius:28px;
```

You can check your CSS codes [here](http://www.css3maker.com)

Answer (score 0):

......................
Give to `border-radius`
 in your `#center` id div

as like this

```
    #center { 
      border-radius:28px 28px 0 0;
-webkit-border-radius:28px 28px 0 0;
-moz-border-radius:28px 28px 0 0;
    }
```

***[Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/vc455m4s)***

Comment: But I don't want the center to have border radius :(

Comment: @sys_debug than your code is fine what problum yar can u post screenshoot of your actual problum